# Sudden GH/s drop in BFL Miner

Tags: asic, butterfly-labs

So basically I have a BLF non-Jalapeno variety 50Gh/s miner. I run cgminer and have recently been mining from ozcoin after eclipsemc was hit with a recent DDoS. 
Normally, I have been clocking at around 46.xxG-50.xxG/50.xx-51.xxGh/s. Last night I noticed a bunch of incoherent errors pop up on my terminal window. About 5-8 lines long. The miner would stall out, it dropped to around 18.xxG/19.xxGh/s stuttered around that level for a few minutes then slowly climbed back up to the rather disappointing 36.xxG-39.xxG/37.xx-39.xxGh/s I have been seeing ever since.
I've poked around looking for reason for this, and maybe haven't poked hard enough, but I am at a loss. Any ideas on what is happening?

Comment: How about asking this question in BLF support?

Comment: Thanks, throwing an I don't know, would have been just as helpful...

Comment: Asking a question, I have a problem that I do not know how to solve, would be just the same as your problem. There is no point to find out what is wrong. There is not enough information. I had some errors and then speed decreased - this is not a question.

Comment: My question was, "any ideas what is happening?" so fair enough, I'm curious if this is something that has happened to other people? If this could be related to the hardware, or perhaps the exchange between the hardware and a mining pool? Or is it possible that the medium, being the computer that sits between the miner and the mining pool could cause a disturbance which disrupts information flow one way or the other? I'm fishing for ideas, or people who've seen this and have some insight. That's all. But it is indeed a question. I just gave as much background information on it as I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both BFL hardware and software are quite unstable, and depend on the starting temperature of the BFL hardware.

What you can do is: stop the mining software, power off the BFL miner, and stick the BFL miner in the freezer for 5-10 minutes (or longer, say 1-2 hours) so that it can cool down.

When I got my 50GH/s, it could only run at around 25GH/s. Eventually, I found out that it is temperature sensitive. I have, once in a while, powered it down, put it in the freezer, and then powered it back up.

I get pretty impressive results that way. From an original of 8 out of 16 chips working, I now get 15 out of 16 chips working.